What is the difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE and CURRENT_DATE?
I created an immutable function as below:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetCurrentDate()
  RETURNS DATE
AS $p$
BEGIN
    RETURN  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE;
END;
$p$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE SECURITY DEFINER;

And I use this in a UNIQUE INDEX's WHERE clause like:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PersonPhoness_UK_PhoneNo_CountryID 
    ON person_phones (phone_no, country_id)
    WHERE   GetCurrentDate() 
        BETWEEN effective_from_date AND effective_till_date;

This unique index sometimes does not catch duplicate when another row is added.
The effective_from_dt for the newly added row is always CURRENT_DATE. However, it works if I change the function to:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetCurrentDate()
RETURNS DATE
AS $p$
BEGIN
    RETURN  CURRENT_DATE;
END
$p$;

So I want to understand the difference.

Answer to question in title
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE and CURRENT_DATE do effectively exactly the same. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE is a tiny bit slower from first getting timestamptz and then coercing it to date - a pointless detour. Either expression is only STABLE, not IMMUTABLE, because either depends on the timezone setting of the executing session.
About your index
The whole approach cannot work. CURRENT_DATE (or any function returning a point in time for that matter) makes no sense in an index definition. The way you have it, a row would enter into the partial index on one day, but not on another. Arbitrary consequences ...
Obviously, Postgres cannot allow that. The manual:

All functions and operators used in an index definition must be
“immutable”, that is, their results must depend only on their
arguments and never on any outside influence (such as the contents of
another table or the current time). This restriction ensures that the
behavior of the index is well-defined. To use a user-defined function
in an index expression or WHERE clause, remember to mark the
function immutable when you create it.

Bold emphasis mine. When trying to violate this rule, CREATE INDEX answers with:

ERROR:  functions in index predicate must be marked IMMUTABLE 


You forced the broken concept with an IMMUTABLE function wrapper. Only do that when it's actually true. Or when you know exactly what you are doing with a white lie.
Your lie isn't white. Whenever a session operates with a different timezone setting, you (can) get a different date for the same point in time and arbitrary things happen. This can go for a long time before you actually realize the broken functionality.
So you have two levels of breakage. Luckily, it surfaced before too long. It's pure coincidence that you saw errors with one function definition and not with the other. Either is bonkers. Pardon my French.
Start by defining your requirements exactly in plain English (or French, if you will). Then look for the proper tool(s) to implement ...
Asides

SECURITY DEFINER is completely useless for this. Only adds cost and possible security implications without any gain.

Avoid mixed-case identifiers if at all possible. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


The second function definition in your question is incomplete without language declaration. And without volatility label IMMUTABLE it wouldn't be accepted by CREATE INDEX to begin with.



Thanks @Erwise-Brandstetter for your inputs. Your concerns are valid. My requirement is... to ensure uniqueness of phone_no and country_id in a table for effective rows with following structure: id (INT), person_id (INT) references persons, phone_no (varchar(15)), country_id (SMALLINT), effective_from_dt (DATE), effective_till_dt (DATE), constraint check (effective_from_dt < effective_till_dt)). On insertion, effective_from_dt is CURRENT_DATE and effective_till_dt is '31 Dec 9999'. When a record becomes ineffective, column effectve_till_dt is updated to yesterday (a day less current_date).

First version is little bit slower:

you execute cast timestamp -> date
you switch execution context from current user to owner of function. The context has not any effect on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP pseudo function, so it is useless. But although it is useless, it has an overhead. Maybe if the owner of function is same user as an application user, then the context is not changed. But this is bad configuration from security reasons.

So both functions returns same result, but first does some useless operations, and then it should be little bit slower.
When you want to "rename" build in functions, then the best is using SQL language for functions instead. It is zero overhead. Starting PL/pgSQL runtime for any execution of any PL/pgSQL function has some overhead:
so
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetCurrentDate()
RETURNS DATE
AS $$ SELECT CURRENT_DATE $$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;

is better. It is inlined in query (not executed), so overhead of this is zero.

Thanks @PavelStehule for the suggestion. Can you throw some light on the behavior of unique index when CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE is used vis-a-vis when CURRENT_DATE is used

@JitendraLoyal - PL/pgSQL functions are black boxes for SQL engine. The optimizer doesn't know so your GetCurrentDate is effectively same function like CURRENT_DATE, and then the index is not used. Your definition of conditional index is wrong - it cannot to work - probably you want to use constraints.

Thanks @PavelStehule. Here my concern is not related to optimization. My requirement is to be ensure that an "effective" (current_date between effective_from_dt and effective_till_dt) phone number in a country is used by one person only.

In PL/pgsql we CAST data two way.

Using Cast() Function: CAST(value as cast_data_type)
Using Cast Operator (::) : value::cast_data_type

So, when you write anything like: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE
It means, cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DATE)
Now we know default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP format is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnnnnn+/-tz and CURRENT_DATE format is YYYY-MM-DD.
So, you tell me what need more time ? @JitendraLoyal
For reference:

Pl/pgSQL TypeCast

The moot point is understanding the reason for Unique Index for failure, which is the difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE and CURRENT_DATE. Kindly throw some light on that.

Definitely CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::DATE will take more time. Because, we need to parse the data from YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.nnnnnn+/-tz to YYYY-MM-DD format. @JitendraLoyal

@ArtBindu - this is not true - internally timestamp is number of seconds from some point, and date is number of days from some points. So cast does only this numeric transformation - see https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/b7d35d393edbe2d4333dde81496e8a362abc85bd/src/backend/utils/adt/date.c#L1341
